# Why is $e$ a good base to use whenever you have a moving exponent

Tags: calculus, limits

While trying to evaluate a limit involving $x^x$ our professor told us that whenever dealing with moving exponents the best thing to do is to use "base $e$", why is that?

Comment: Could you please clarify what "moving exponent" means?

Comment: That would depend on what you actually want to do with this $x^x$. But yes, using the fact that $x^x = e^{x\ln x}$ is helpful in particular because $e^x$ and $\ln x$ have nice analytical properties. Particularly simple derivatives. Moreover you most likely defined $x^x$ as $e^{x\ln x}$ anyways.

Comment: @TobErnack you might want to post that as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $e$ simplifies lot of calculation, because number $e$ itself is the result of simple analytic processes. We can use any other number like $2$ and write $x^x=2^{x\log_{2}x}$ but then the derivatives of $2^x$ and $\log_{2}x$ don't have as simple forms as those of $e^x, \log x$. The functions $e^x, \log x$ have been created to have simple derivatives.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the function $y=e^x$ enjoys the property that it is its own derivative. problems involving motion normally require differentiation and integration.

$y=e^x$, is also its own integral. Hyperbolic functions are defined by combinations of exponential functions and the story goes on and on.

Answer (score 0):

In fact $a^b$ is well defined when $a$ and $b$ are rational numbers since we can write $\large \left(\dfrac pq\right)^\frac st=\dfrac{\sqrt[t]{p^s}}{\sqrt[t]{q^s}}$

These operation on integers are well known, $x^b$ is also well defined for a real $x$ and $b$ rational.

But when $b$ is a real number all we have is a limit of the rational expressions above.

To solve this issue, a solution was found by creating the logarithm and exponential function $\ln$ and $\exp$.

The exponential function is defined in a totally different way by $\exp(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{x^k}{k!}$ and one could also verify it is the limit of $(1+\frac xn)^n$.

Then we state, let's have $$a^b=\exp(b\ln(a))$$

Through the properties $\ln(xy)=\ln(x)+\ln(y)$ and $\exp(x+y)=\exp(x)\exp(y)$ and $\ln(1)=0$,

you can verify that this new definition of $a^b$ coincide with natural $a^b$ for $a,b$ rationals.

Finally by continuity this definition is extended to real numbers.

It is then a convention to note $e=\exp(1)$ and $\exp(x)=e^x$.

But you have to see that we in fact do not elevate $e$ to the real power $x$, thing we are not able to do directly, instead we rely on the exponential function.

This is the same for $f(x)^{g(x)}$, the only reasonable meaning we have for this expression is $\exp(g(x)\ln(f(x)))$ and it is still a convention to write it $e^{g(x)\ln(f(x))}$ but keep in mind this is not $e$ elevated to a certain power $h(x)$ but indeed the evaluation of the exponential function at $h(x)$.